# How can I find out the number of dimensions in a multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, vbscript

Is there a way to do this without using On Error Resume Next?

All the solutions I see count the dimensions by assuming X dimension  DOES exist and then suppressing the error if one occurs.

It works, but if feels kind of dirty. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. (And what's good enough for [M. Harris](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/r_phCajLWHA) is good enough for me.)